# Why do I need an AssemblyResolve handler for an assembly which is already loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

I have two assemblies: `App` and `AddOn`.  `App` references `AddOn`, but `CopyLocal` is set to `false`, since `AddOn` will be loaded dynamically by `App`.

Here is the code in `AddOn`:

```
namespace AddOn
{
    public class AddOnClass
    {
        public static void DoAddOnStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AddOn is doing stuff.");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code in `App`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly.LoadFrom(@"..\..\..\AddOn\bin\Debug\AddOn.dll");

        // Without this event handler, we get a FileNotFoundException.
        // AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
        // {
        //     return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        //                     .FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == e.Name);
        //};

        CallAddOn();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private static void CallAddOn()
    {
        AddOnClass.DoAddOnStuff();
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why the code doesn't work with the `AssemblyResolve` handler commented in `Main()`. When run in Visual Studio, the debugger breaks on `CallAddOn()` with a `FileNotFoundException`.  Why is it complaining? The assembly is loaded, and it's the exact same version (i.e. same file on disk) as what was referenced by `App`.

I feel like there is some fundamental concept that I'm not understanding properly here. The commented `AssemblyResolve` handler works fine, but it seems like a hack and I don't understand why I need it because it seems like it's doing something trivial.

Comment: You are doing this wrong.  When you allow add-ons to be used in your program then you *don't know* the type of the class in the add-on.  It was written by another programmer.  So you should be pretty interested in the return value of LoadFrom(), you'll for example use Assembly.GetType() to discover a type.

Comment: It's an addon that's referencing another addon because it's relying on that functionality.

Comment: That is not an addon, just a normal dependent assembly.  You always use Copy Local = True to ensure that the CLR can find the assembly automatically without you having to help.  Which is the default setting.

Comment: The problem is that the host already has AddOn1 loaded, and AddOn2 wants to take advantage of this, without having to include AddOn1 itself (which it can't do anyway due to licensing reasons)

Comment: That's a very short path to DLL Hell.  These kind of license restrictions are often designed to stop you from shooting your leg off like that.  They don't just forbid adding a reference, they forbid *using* the code in the DLL.  Best to ask your company's legal counsel to review the license terms, this can get you in trouble.

Comment: @HansPassant: Point taken, but I'm not sure what's the best way to allow what I want. I posted this as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20221340/270348

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that there are multiple assembly loading contexts. The context which an assembly is loaded into affects how it can be used. When an assembly is loaded by the runtime using the default probing mechanism it is put into the so-called Load context. This is the context used when you load an assembly via `Assembly.Load`. You have loaded the assembly using `LoadFrom` which uses its own context. Probing does not examine the LoadFrom context and the file is not in the probing path so you are required to resolve it for the runtime. This is not symmetric however. If an assembly is loaded in the Load context, `LoadFrom` will load it from there first (assuming the identity is the same. for unsigned assemblies, the path is part of the identity.). I will note there are more contexts including `ReflectionOnlyLoad` and `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`. `LoadFile` loads an assembly without a context, i.e. all dependencies must be manually loaded.

If you want assemblies to be resolved in the Load context, but have them exist outside the application's default probing path you can do it via configuration as well. Use either the [`<codebase>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element of an assembly binding redirect or the `privatePath` attribute of the [`<probing>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element.

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information. There are also some blog posts by Suzanne Cook from a while back on assembly loading and contexts (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/13/switching-to-the-load-context.aspx), and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx)).